# Android Studio plugin Gradle errors

Tags: android-studio, gradle

So i just wanted to creat a hello world app and this happened

Build file 'C:\Users\Yuness\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\build.gradle' line: 3

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Exception is: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.1.2') Searched in the following repositories: Gradle Central Plugin Repository Google MavenRepo

Comment: Have you got your answer? If yes, comment here. I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of basic steps when you get this type of error

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

1 - You have to check if Gradle is working in offline mode and the solution is in the right side menu "Click Toggle Offline Mode" if it is active.

[image]

2- Go to "File -> Setting -> (settings cogwheel) -> Http Proxy Setting" and check which proxy setting you are using.

[image]

[image]

I hope this solves your problem with Gradle.

Comment: Not working. Try both things.

Answer (score 0):

if your project is open in android studio, follow these simple steps as seen in the below screenshot

1. click on the project tab at the top - left of your android studio app.
2. Down your project structure, click on Gradle Scripts. In the drop down, you  will see two build.gradle files
3. Open the build.gradle with (Module:Application_Name.app)
4. Inside the build.gradle file opened, make sure the it contains the following at the top.

   plugins {  id 'com.android.application'}
5. Then build your application.

if you still receive this error, then open the other build.gradle file with (Project:Application_Name)

6. check for plugin section and paste this below

   plugins {

   id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false

   id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false

   }
7. Build your application.

if you dont find any of these file, it means you need to create the build.gradle. but as a beginner, is better to delete the project and create it again.

please make sure your internet is active to sync your gradle

[gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Vaa.png)

Comment: it doesnt work i cant find 2 build.gradle its only one and it didnt work
but thank you, please can you help?

Comment: It means that means that you need to create the build.gradle files. but the best is to create new project, make sure you have internet connection and gradle will sync automatically

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

1. Go to 'File'
2. Click on 'Sync Project with Gradle files'
3. Make sure you have internet connected

Comment: it doesnt work !!

Comment: what's the version your studio